# Running Ionic for Android on JDK 11

Tags: java, ionic4

I can run the command "ionic cordova run android --device" on JDK 1.8 just fine. How can i run JDK 11 withouth getting the error message "JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11
Requirements check failed for JDK 1.8"

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for that problem?

Answer (score 0):

when you install jdk 11 in a machine which has jdk 8 in it, Java Home doesn't changes to jdk 11. you have to manually change it.
Open your command prompt and type "javac -version" if you see there something like "jdk 1.8.191" then your Java Home is currently set to jdk 1.8